# Swift: Chain Textfields for Next Button

Tags: iphone, swift, uitextfield, ios8, interface-builder

How does one simply chain up a few textfields for a form?

I found an old Post for obj-C here and unsuccessfully tried to "swift it".

What I tried to do:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!

nameTextfield.addTarget(target: emailTextfield, action: becomeFirstResponder(), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEndOnExit)
```

Do you have to target the textfield in an other way than by its IBOutlet?

Answer (score 1):

add this function:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

After return is hit on each textfield the keyboard will resign.  You can add tags to your textfields and then add if/else statements for different behaviors depending on which textField.tag responded if you wish.

You do not have to target the textfield by anything other than the IBOutlet for this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try out this code.

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {

        if (usernameTF.resignFirstResponder())
        {
            passwordTF.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        textField.resignFirstResponder();


        return true
    }
```